# php include from main folder to a file in different folder

Tags: php

in my root folder of my domain i have files header.php and footer.php, i have created a new folder and file in the new folder and wanted to include the header and footer files from main. So the paths are:
main folder: example.com/header.php
new file: example.com/folder/new_file.php <- in this file i want to include the header.

I have tried:

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
<?php include "/header.php"; ?>
<?php include "./header.php"; ?>
<?php include "../header.php"; ?>
```

and none of them work. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: The last one *should* work, assuming the file system structure matches the URL structure you're showing.  Does it?  How are you confirming that this works or not?  Is there an error or warning in the PHP logs?

Comment: Hi David. I managed to get the last one to work ( not sure why it dint before) but now im facing the problem that even do all the text is there, it is not reading the css files inside the header.php file

Comment: in header i have the links to .css files + navbar, navbar shows all text but no css has been applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php' ); ?>
```

it's will work .try may be its help in any of your files

Comment: This also worked but it is not reading the links for css files with in the header file. All files on main root are displayed ok

Comment: try to use absolute paths from the webroot:
href="/css/style.css"

Answer (score 0):

```
include_once dirname(__DIR__).'/header.php';
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your support. To answer my question thanks to all here are the answers.

```
<?php include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/header.php' ); ?>
```

and
    php include "../header.php";

DO work and i was able to include a file from main directory so thanks to david and code360.

second part of why the css file was not being read is because i had it like this in header.php file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
```

and missed the first "/"

Thanks again to code360

Comment: you welcome my friend Richard Epton :) we are here to help each other .give vote my answer.